# Password validation not working in Angular

Tags: angularjs, html

Hi I am trying to validate password using ng-show and error messages are displayed even though the password is correct and also are displayed on page refresh.

My code is  : Form name is : registeruser

```
<!-- Set a password for the account -->
                        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin: 7px;">
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" style="height: 35px;" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" ng-model="register_password" required autocomplete="off" />
                            <!-- Button for viewing password -->
                            <input type="checkbox" id="eye" onclick="if(password.type=='text')password.type='password'; else password.type='text';" />
                        </div>
                        <!-- Error Message for password -->
                        <div class="error-message" ng-show="registeruser.password.$invalid">
                            Please enter at least 6 characters.
                        </div>
                        <div class="error-message" ng-show="registeruser.password.$pristine">
                            Please enter your password.
                        </div>
```

I checked the ng-show with the placeholder name, id and model name but it not working. 
Also I want the password error to be displayed if the user tabs out of the password field without entering the password and not on page load when the password field is empty.

Comment: Use ng-messages for form validation. It is the easy and better way to implement validations and will do a lot of checks OOB for you. Below link explains http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/05/how-to-use-ngmessages-in-angularjs.html

Answer (score 0):

use `$dirty` in addition with `$invalid` to display error-message. `$dirty` is set by angular to determine if user put anything on input.
If you want error-message displayed only if input get and lost focus without any text you should use `ng-blur/ng-focus` to manage entry/exit on input.
By default angular manage only when user insert text in input via $dirty but detect no changes if user enter and exit from the input without entering text.

Use of `$dirty` :

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" style="height: 35px;" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" ng-model="register_password" required autocomplete="off" ng-minlength="6" />
<!-- Error Message for password -->
                    <div class="error-message" ng-show="registeruser.password.$invalid && registeruser.password.$dirty">
                        Please enter at least 6 characters.
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Here "formSubmitted" is a scope variable set while the submit button is clicked. You can set it in the controller like $scope.formSubmitted = true; inside a function and call it using ng-click of the submit button. Note: The use of ng-minlength for checking the minimum 6 characters requirement.

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin: 7px;">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" style="height: 35px;" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" ng-minlength="6" required autocomplete="off" />
     </div>

    <!-- Error Message for password -->
    <div class="error-message" ng-show="(registeruser.password.$error.minlength && !registeruser.password.$pristine) ||  (registeruser.password.$pristine && formSubmitted)">
           Please enter at least 6 characters.
    </div>
    <div class="error-message" ng-show="(registeruser.password.$error.required && !registeruser.password.$pristine) || (registeruser.password.$pristine && formSubmitted)">
           Please enter your password.
    </div>
```